# Change vertical direction of data across x-axis based on y-axis value Google charts

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

I am using google chart(column chart), the scenario is that when value is less than 100 it should be shown in y-axis negative direction and when value is equal to or above 100 then value be shown in positive direction.
[required o/p format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqwI4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

set config option `hAxis.baseline: 100`

note: This option is only supported for a [continuous](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#Terminology) axis.